# Can players from different platforms join the same clan?

Tags: call-of-duty-ghosts

I know you can't play cross-platform, but can people who play CoD Ghost on a PC or Xbox join a clan that is mostly of PS4 and PS3 players?

Apparently PS3 and PS4 can, we have 2 players competing with us on the PS3 platform, but how about the rest of the platforms?

Comment: In black ops 2 I know you could because of ELITE, however I don't think ghosts uses ELITE so I'll have to do a bit of research on it to be sure.

Comment: They're supposed to be able to but I've not found a way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You can, what you need to is log on to the Call of Duty app and there is a button at the top right to switch between platform.